# Why reputation isn't increasing when I accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Hello!
Few days ago I've asked a couple of questions about some technology on SO. On next day I've found the answers to my questions by myself and posted the answers. One of the questions was very basic, but the answer for it can be useful for the next person who will ask similar question. The second question was much more interesting and non-trivial. I've posted a compact solution to the problem and it surely may be useful for someone.
Today I've accepted both answers and noticed that my rating wasn't changed. Why such difference? I mean if I accept some answer written by different person I got the reward and if I accept my own answer I got nothing?

Comment: See [How does reputation work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow) in [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's precisely right - it's to avoid you trying to game the system by asking questions, providing answers to them and then accepting them over and over again. See [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) for more details.

Comment: I agree with Jon, but I think that this also discourages people from sharing there findings, thus leaving the question potentially unanswered for quite a while, maybe even indefinitly. I think S/O should change this rule slightly so that it only stops rewarding you after your second or third self-answered-question within a certain time-frame.

Comment: @j-t-s: If you wish to answer your own question, that is completely acceptable. You gain reputation if others agree when your answer/findings are up-voted. I find nothing discouraging about the design or implementation of this feature.